# Generating Random Line from Text File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file of random codes.
ex.

> j23j423j4
>
> j23j42j34
>
> 234j234j2

Each time the webpage is loaded I would like a random line to be generated and displayed.

In my head I was thinking of making an array off all the lines, then choosing a random line from the array. What is the best way to approach this? I have never worked with txt files and jQuery.

Comment: Why do you want a random line?  And what is the real format of your 'random' line?  If you just want a number, then use `Math.random`.

Comment: Do you want to actually import from the .txt file? Are you able to manipulate the file a bit?

Comment: if I were you, and were able to. I would put try to push each line into an array and then just use a random number as the index in the array.

Comment: couldn't you make a function to generate a random code whenever you call it? no reading files, no list of random codes, just generating them on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to place the txt file somewhere (webserver eg.). 
Now you have 2 options (maybe more :-D):

1. Pull the txt file via webrequest
2. Use php to insert it in js (or something similar)

Since this is a js question assume the first option.

(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
//This loads your file from somewhere
$.get( "text.txt", function( data ) {
    //Split data by lines if its in a formated format (like json you have to decode or parse the data)
    var lines = data.split("/n"));

    //Random item number
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

    //Get random line
    var line = lines[r];

    alert(line);
});
```

That should give you a hint

Comment: This is perfect guidance. Thank you!